# Using substring to rename multiple file names using C#

Tags: c#

I need to rename multiple CSV file names. I want to remove everything after the "-" so for example "File-1.csv" will become just "File.csv". Here's my code that's not working:

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\folder");
FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
{
    File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.ToString().Substring(0, f.LastIndexOf('-')));
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error 2 'System.IO.FileInfo' does not contain a definition for 'LastIndexOf' and no extension method 'LastIndexOf' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.FileInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I fix this?

Comment: So what's it doing vs what you want it to be doing? (My guess is that it's dropping the extension - so that's what you should be looking at. That has nothing to do with the "multiple" part... get it working for a single file and I'd expect it to be fine with multiple files.)

Comment: Hi, im getting this error - Error 2 'System.IO.FileInfo' does not contain a definition for 'LastIndexOf' and no extension method 'LastIndexOf' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.FileInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Im really new to c# and i think it means theres a namespace missing, but ive tired googling and i cant work it out

Comment: No, it doesn't mean there's a namespace missing. Look at the *exact* error message you're getting. You're trying to call `LastIndexOf()` on a `System.IO.FileInfo`. Is that what you meant to do? Did you look for that method in the documentation for `System.IO.FileInfo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't compile because you are calling `.LastIndexOf()` on the `FileInfo` object when you should be calling it on `FileInfo.FullName`. Your substring also chops off the extension from the filename string, which I don't think you want. Here is a solution that preserves the extension:

```
foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
{
    // Get the extension string from the existing file
    var extension = f.FullName.Substring(f.FullName.LastIndexOf('.'), f.FullName.Length - 1);

    // Get the filename, excluding the '-' as well as the extension
    var filename = f.FullName.SubString(0, f.FullName.LastIndexOf('-'));

    // Concatenate the filename and extension and move the file
    File.Move(f.FullName, String.Format("{0}{1}", filename, extension));
}
```

Comment: I think this solution would still miss the extension of the file right?

Comment: @Sam.C updated with a more verbose solution that preserves the extension.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm getting this error:
>
> Error 2 'System.IO.FileInfo' does not contain
>   a definition for 'LastIndexOf'

`f` is not string; try f.FullName.LastIndexOf...